# Partially read standard output of another process created from c# application

Tags: c#, process, redirect, standards

I have a GUI application within which i'm spawning a console application using Process class.

```
Process p1 = new Process();
p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p1.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(basepath, "abc.exe");
p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/pn abc.exe /f \"temp1.txt\"";
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p1.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(outputreceived);
p1.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(errorreceived);
p1.Start();
tocmd = p1.StandardInput;
p1.BeginOutputReadLine();
p1.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Now i have a problem that, though it reads the console output asynchronously but it seems to fire the event only when the internal buffer is filled with some amount. I want it to display data as it comes. If there's 10 bytes in buffer, let it display the 10 bytes. My program implements sleep() call internally, so i need to print the data till it goes to sleep.

How can i do it?

=============

As it was mentioned the output is line buffered, i tried the following change in the code

```
p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p1.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(basepath, "abc.exe");
p1.StartInfo.Arguments = pnswitch + " /f \"temp1.txt\"";
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p1.Start();
tocmd = p1.StandardInput;
MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(readout);
mi.BeginInvoke(null, p1);
```

and inside readout i wrote

```
void readout()
    {
        string str;
        while ((str = p1.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            richTextBox1.Invoke(new UpdateOutputCallback(this.updateoutput), new object[] { str });
            p1.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Flush();
        }
    }
```

So i think it now monitors when each line is written and it prints it right? this too didn't work. Any thing wrong there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Output and Error Data received is line buffered, and will only fire when a newline is added.

Your best bet is to use you own reader that can read the input, byte by byte. Obvioulsly, this would have to be non-blocking  :)

Comment: any idea as how can i go about making my own reader? Can't i write some function which monitors the stdoutput stream and reads from it everytime it has some data?

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. You read the StandardOutput from another thread.

Comment: i've changed the code, and made it read line wise. can you have a look?

Comment: Dont use ReadLine! Use Read() instead, and cast to char, then append to string or write somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you must use synchronous read operations on a redirected stream.
Your code would look like this (MSDN Sample):

```
// Start the child process.
Process p = new Process();
// Redirect the output stream of the child process.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
p.Start();
// Do not wait for the child process to exit before
// reading to the end of its redirected stream.
// p.WaitForExit();
// Read the output stream first and then wait.
**string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();**
p.WaitForExit();
```

In order to achieve async behavior you would have to use some threads.

MSDN Article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)

Comment: I made a async call to it. Can you have a look at the updated question and comment on it?